# Processing Time for plotting and numeric calculation in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, plot, numeric, cpu-speed

I have a function which in total takes 34s and I want to speed this up. The 2 slowest functions are:

1) I have a very simple function file:

```
function [x] = percentChange(startPoint, currentPoint)
x = ( (currentPoint-startPoint)/abs(startPoint) )*100.00;
```

where currentPoint and startPoint are just integers. 
During my main function I call this function 1.114.239 times (which takes my computer 13.364s). Can I make this any faster?

2) Another part of my function which takes quite a while is the plotting of 1934 lines. Currently, the plotting is done as follows:

```
for i=1:size(patternPlot,1)
    hold all
    plot(xplot,patternPlot(i,:)); 
end
```

'patternPlot' stores the vectors i want to plot (xplot is just the vector 1:30). Can I speed this up in any way?

Thanks in advance,

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 1): remove outer parentheses in second line. Probably won't gain speed; just for clarity.

Do you really have to call that function so many times, each with a number? Can't you do `(currentPoint-startPoint)./abs(startPoint)*100.00` where `currentPoint`and `startPoint` are *vectors*?

In 2): instead of the loop do a single, "vectorized plot": `plot(xplot,patternPlot)`, or better `plot(patternPlot.')`. That will plot everything in a single step.

Comment: Thanks! The speed of number 2 is reduced from 7s to 0.498975s and number 1 seems to be 1s faster (although i'm not sure if the removal of those brackets has anything to do with it)

Comment: @user84112 Welcome! Well, that's better than nothing. Maybe someone will come up with further reductions